# Optimize MS ACCESS SQL with Nested Sub-Queries

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, optimization, subquery

## Problem

I am working in a MS Access database that converts entries from invoices into accounting general ledger codes. The database on occasion ‘splits’ records (e.g. an invoice including a single charge might need to have that charge allocated across several different business units). I have written an SQL query to delete the ‘parent’ records after the ‘split’ records are inserted into the database's table with an INSERT INTO query. Unfortunately, I have written this through mostly trial and error, and it runs extremely slowly (I believe as a result of the nested sub-queries).

***What can I do in order to optimize this query?***

### Illustration of Database

**As an illustration, if a table contained the following:**
[Type]----[Charge]----[Description]-------------------[Invoice Amount]
5000------NoDept------40 SQL Helmets--------------$500

**A split of that record could look like:**
[Type]----[Charge]----[Description]-------------------[Invoice Amount]
5000------NoDept------40 SQL Helmets--------------$500
5000------NoDept------40 SQL Helmets_%Split----$200
5000------NoDept------40 SQL Helmets_%Split----$75
5000------NoDept------40 SQL Helmets_%Split----$225

**And after my SQL statement cleans up the table, it should be left like this:**
[Type]----[Charge]----[Description]-------------------[Invoice Amount]
5000------NoDept------40 SQL Helmets_%Split----$200
5000------NoDept------40 SQL Helmets_%Split----$75
5000------NoDept------40 SQL Helmets_%Split----$225

### Current SQL

```
DELETE * 
FROM [tblManipulateW] 
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT SUM([Dupe].[Invoice Amount]) AS [SumInvoices], 
    [Dupe].[Type], 
        [Dupe].[Charge], 
        LEFT([Dupe].[Description], Len([Dupe].[Description]) - 7) As DescriptionLessSplit 
        FROM [tblManipulateW] AS [Dupe] 
        GROUP BY [Dupe].[Type], 
        [Dupe].[Charge], 
        LEFT([Dupe].[Description], LEN([Dupe].[Description])-7), 
        [Dupe].[Description] LIKE "*_%Split"
        HAVING [Dupe].[Description] LIKE "*_%Split") AS [Dupe2] 
    WHERE [Dupe2].[DescriptionLessSplit] = [tblManipulateW].[Description] 
    AND [Dupe2].[Type] = [tblManipulateW].[Type] 
    AND ROUND([Dupe2].[SumInvoices],2) = ROUND([tblManipulateW].[Invoice Amount],2) 
    AND [Dupe2].[Charge] = [tblManipulateW].[Charge]);
```

### SQL Explanation

The sub-sub-query builds a query called **Dupe2** that finds all alike charges that have been split and returns:
- the sum of their invoice amount
- their description less the phrase “_%Split”
- their Charge code
- their Type code

The sub-query is checking to see when items in the main table match those as returned from the sub-sub-query a.k.a. Dupe2. If an entry does match each field, then it will be deleted.

Thank you very much for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend adding two more columns to your `tblManipulateW` table: an autoincrement primary key (`ID`), and a `ParentID` column (which can be `null`) so that a split can optionally identify its parent. Here's why.

Imagine you have such a primary key. And suppose your '40 SQL Helmets' entry for $500 originally has `ID` 25. Now when you do your split routine, instead of appending some text to the `Description`, you can actually set the `ParentID` for all the child splits to 25. Now you can find all the parent splits very easily--they're all the splits that have children:

```
select t1.*
from tblManipulateW as t1
inner join tblManipulateW as t2
on t1.ID = t2.ParentID
```

This query is very easy to optimise--in fact Access will do it for you automatically if you set up the `ID` column to be an autoincrement primary key. And there's the added benefit that the data is more normalised than before (you're storing the parent-child relationship in a separate column instead of some text added to the `Description` column).

Addendum: there is one more important optimisation you can do: make the `ParentID` column a foreign key that references the `ID` column. The following should work to do that:`*`

```
alter table tblManipulateW
add column ParentID long
constraint ManipulateW_ParentID
references tblManipulateW (ID)
on delete set null;
```

The above fully describes the `ParentID` column. The last line (`on delete set null`) is optional; it just helps preserve referential integrity by setting the `ParentID` value in a split to `null` automatically if the parent split gets deleted.

The benefit of making `ParentID` a foreign key is that Access will implement it as an index in the database, which will automatically speed up the join I show earlier.

`*` Note that this SQL is in the ANSI-92 syntax, which is not supported in the Access 'front-end' SQL editor. You will need to execute it with a little VBA: `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "alter table ..."`.

Comment: Argh- talk about a case of 'Keep It Simple, Stupid' being the best strategy! Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Glad it helps. I actually can suggest another optimisation, will revise my answer with details when I get home.